# OpenVPN internet remote connection (server&client)

Tags: openvpn, tunnel

So my work network blocks torrent connections, but I have a home computer that I can use as a server. I have created both certificates and keys for client (my laptop) and server(s) (home computer), and so I have opened the port on my router, but I am really struggling with the config files. I guess I need to link an UDP and TCP servers over TUN, but how do I redirect the client to the server's internet connection?

*I am sorry if I don't explain me well enough I am really noobish with all of this.*

Can somebody help me with these files?

Answer (score 0):

Your client configuration should connect to your public IP (just ask google about "my IP", when you are behind your router).

Assuming you did configure your router to forward TCP (or UDP) port 443 to your OpenVPN server, then your client configuration would include:

```
remote 1.2.3.4 443
```

Note that such configuration may not work from behind your router (in some cases, the port redirection could be only valid for traffic arriving from outside your home network). If so, you can test/troubleshoot connecting directly to your OpenVPN server private IP.

Usually, running OpenVPN, you would only need UDP or TCP. Not both.

Comment: So, does the bittorrent protocol use UDP or TCP?

Comment: The point of running OpenVPN is to route your traffic through a tunnel. Regardless of the protocol. OpenVPN would run using UDP, or TCP. It is for you to pick, depending on how you configured your server/what traffic would be allowed in your router. Then, your torrent client would probably also require some UDP port redirection on your router, forwarding traffic back to your torrent client.

Comment: And you'll probably prefer running your torrent client on a station physically located behind your router. Knowing what your OpenVPN configuration looks like, and how your OpenVPN clients leave the server (especially: do you NAT? or just forward?) would help.